# Speech on WinRT

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, speech, text-to-speech

1. Is Speech api available in WinRT (like Windows Phone 8).
2. Can I use some third party speech api instead?

I want to implement TTS in my Windows 8/WinRT application, does anyone have some suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Speech is now available for WinRT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn630426.aspx)

Voice Commands and Speech Recognition are available on phone only.

TTS is available for all winRT devices.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Speech API available in WinRT.

There may be 3rd party WinRT components, you would have to look for those.  I am not aware of any, but I only did a cursory search.

If being connected to the internet as an app requirement is not a problem, you can use http://translatorservice.codeplex.com/

Comment: Speech synthesis was added in Windows 8.1, see #gravidThought's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [Bing Speech Control](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/521cf616-a9a8-4d99-b5d9-92b539d9df82) for Windows 8.1 has a nearly identical API set to that of the speech recognition APIs on Windows Phone. It is not difficult to create an abstraction around them that can work in a universal app. Unfortunately the speech control for Windows 8 does require an internet connection for speech recognition.

For text to speech only (not recognition), those APIs were added directly to Windows 8.1. They are in the [Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.speechsynthesis.aspx) namespace.