# How to update status facebook from windows 8 apps?

Tags: c#, facebook, xaml, windows-8, speech-recognition

I am building a Windows 8 app which allow use Facebook and Twitter and Google...etc via speech recognition but I am stuck on the code to update status Facebook by speech Is this possible??

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to find speech recognition 3rd party library, which is not available in WinRT. Then you can use [Facebook SDK for Windows 8 apps](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/windows/) to perform all the operations of Facebook. Also see these.

[Text-To-Speech with Microsoft Translator Service - Windows Runtime Component](https://translatorservice.codeplex.com/releases/view/97104)

[Speech on WinRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183289/speech-on-winrt)

[Speech Recognition in Windows 8 (rather than having to hit a pesky button)](http://everythingworkflow.wordpress.com/2012/06/19/speech-recognition-in-windows-8-rather-than-having-to-hit-a-pesky-button/)

[Speech Recognition - MSDN Forum Building Windows Store apps with C# or VB](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/968d1f79-1f26-4eb7-88c2-5fa5c7877d4b)